# C# How can I keep my program from invoking my presentation class methods twice?

Tags: c#, .net, methods

```
class MultTableApp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //instantiate new multtable object and pass base values through
        MultTable table1 = new MultTable(GetFirstBaseValue(), GetSecondBaseValue());
        table1.MultTableHeader(); 
        table1.CreateMultTable(); 
        Console.Read(); 
    }

    public static int GetFirstBaseValue()
    {
        int first;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first base value (must be between 2 and 8): ");
        first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (first < 2 || first > 7)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the first base value (must be between 2 and 8): ");
            first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        return first; 
    }

    public static int GetSecondBaseValue()
    {
        int second;
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the second base value (must be between 2 - 8 "
                            + "and larger than first value): ");
        second = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (second <= GetFirstBaseValue() || second > 8)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the second base value (must be between 2 - 8 "
                            + "and larger than first value): ");
            second = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        return second;
    }
}
```

This program accepts a first value and second value then displays a multiplication table for the range of first value to the second value (so if I type in 2 for the first value then 8 for the second value, the program will create a multiplication table for numbers 2-8). Through this class it asks the user for input then passes the input through the new object argument to the logic layer. I didn't include my logic layer because it's already figured out. My problem lies in my presentation layer with the two methods GetFirstValue() and GetSecondValue(). My program invokes both methods twice.

I've stepped through the program and it's having a problem with me using GetFirstValue() as part of my argument in the while loop of the GetSecondValue() method. In fact, I don't even think it's returning a value in the second method the first time it's invoked. After the program asks for the two values, it invokes the GetFirstValue() method once more then creates the multiplication table just fine, but I don't think my while loop in GetSecondValue() is being considered.

My guess is that I need to find a way to use the value from GetFirstValue() in the second method properly, then maybe that will fix it. This is for a business centered programming class, meaning my instructor wants programs divided into presentation, business, and data layers. How can I keep these questions in this presentation class and still achieve a what I'm going for? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Look at condition in `while` loop in `GetSecondBaseValue()`. There you call `GetFirstBaseValue()` which is not what you want. In `Main` you should invoke method, store return value and pass it as parameter like in declaration `GetSecondBaseValue(int first)`. Other than that, you can make these two methods `private` to see if it compiles (or classes in other layers depend on them).

Comment: @nrodic Works perfectly. Must of been having a brain fart. Thanks for the clarification.